# What's the Best connections settings for pgpool-4.4.0 with PostgreSQL-12.5

Tags: postgresql-12, pgpool

I'm new on the pgpool and I really wants to work on it but just stuck with handling the connections parameters setting with postgres db.

**Problem:** I'm seeing a huge number of idle connections and it's degrading my DB performance also it creating problem for new clients. ERR: Too many clients etc.

**Current Pgpool Setting:**

```
process_management_mode = dynamic
process_management_strategy = gentle
num_init_children = 750
min_spare_children = 10
max_spare_children = 20
max_pool = 2

child_life_time = 5min
child_max_connections = 0
connection_life_time = 0
client_idle_limit = 1h
```

**Postgres connections setting:**

```
max_connections = 750
superuser_reserved_connections = 10
```

**Note:** The above parameters has been set by someone before me I dont know what was the intention.

**Observation:** I observed once the new connection comes in and completed its work but after that still its showing in idle state without any reason even my idle state limit = 1hr (`client_idle_limit = 1h`).

So what's the point for this limit or I'm reading this wrongly can't say right now.

**Questions:**

1. Is it correct connection setting for volatile production server?
2. What is the best practice to set the connection limit.
3. is it compulsory to set pgpool num_init_children and postgres max_conncetions same values?
4. how max_pool affects on number of connections & the performance
5. confused between child_life_time and connection_life_time.

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask] Many of your questions, too, ask for opinion which is not allowed here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too with pgpool but checking your settings, I would say you need to decrease the max_pool to 1, instead of 2 or change the num_init_children to 375.

> max_pool (integer)
> The maximum number of cached connections in each Pgpool-II child process. Pgpool-II reuses the cached connection if an incoming connection is connecting to the same database with the same user name and the same run-time parameters. If not, Pgpool-II creates a new connection to the backend. If the number of cached connections exceeds max_pool, the oldest connection will be discarded, and uses that slot for the new connection.

> Default value is 4. Please be aware that the number of connections from Pgpool-II processes to the backends may reach num_init_children * max_pool in total.

You can check this info about both settings:
[Relationship between max pool, num init children, and max connections](https://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Relationship_between_max_pool,_num_init_children,_and_max_connections)

Hope it helps